# Use the Archimedian property to verify values and prove existence for $\sup$ and $\inf$ of a certain sequence of rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $S=\left\{\frac{1}{n^2}:n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$. Prove that $\sup(S)=\max(S)=1$, and $\inf(S)=0$ and $S$ has no $\min$.

Comment: Both assertions are false.

Comment: If $S=\{\frac{1}{n^2}:n\in \mathbb{N}\},$ which equals $\{1,\,1/4,\,1/9,\,1/16,\,\ldots\},$ then it's rather obvious that $\sup(S)=\max(S)=1$ and $\inf(S)=0$ and $\min(S)$ does not exist. As for proving this, you probably need to give more context regarding what you can use, what level this is, etc. Incidentally, as a general rule (which you might wish to remember, as well as know how to prove at the level you're working at here) if the maximum of a set of numbers exists, then the supremum of the set is equal to the maximum.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, wrong answer. I edited it.

Comment: Also I am wondering how to prove this by the Archimedean Property.

Comment: "Also I am wondering how to prove this by the Archimedean Property.".  For any $M$ there is an $n$ so that $M \le \max(M,1) < n < n^2$.  So for any $\epsilon > 0$ then is an $n$ so that $n^2 > \frac 1{\epsilon}$ therefore $0 < \frac 1{n^2} < \epsilon$.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title.  Yours applies to most problems on this site!

Comment: @Andrew Ostergaard: Nice change of title (as if it matters now), since sequences always have an inf and a sup, something I should have realized but for some reason I overlooked.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n\ge 1\implies \frac 1{n^2}\le\frac 1n\le 1$ so $\sup(S)\le 1$.

But since $1\in S$ for $n=1$ then $\sup(S)=\max(S)=1$.

$n>0\implies \frac 1{n^2}>0$ so $\inf(S)\ge 0$.

From Archimedean property $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists n\mid n\epsilon>1\implies\frac 1{n^2}<\frac 1n<\epsilon$ and $\inf(S)=0$.

Now there does not exist an integer such that $n\times 0=1$ so $S$ has no minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Show that $0$ is a lower bound.

for all $n > 0, \frac{1}{n^2} > 0$

Show that $0$ is the greatest lower bound.

Suppose there exists a $B > 0$ such that $B$ is the lower bound of $S.$

There exists an $N$ such that $n >  N \implies \frac 1{n^2} > B$

$\inf (S) = 0$

If $S$ were to achieve its minimum, the that minimum would be the infimum of the set.  But since 0 is not in S, S does not achieve its minimum.